# How do you write a completion handler in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

I was wondering how to make a completion handler for a function I'm creating in Swift 3.
This is how I did my function right before I updated to Swift 3:

```
func Logout(completionHandler: (success: Bool) -> ()) {
    backendless.userService.logout(
        { ( user : AnyObject!) -> () in
            print("User logged out.")
            completionHandler(success: true)
        },
        error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
            completionHandler(success: false)
    })}
```

But now I can't figure out the best approach that works right now.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In Swift 3 the function parameter labels in closures are gone.

Remove all occurrences of `success:` and add `@escaping`

```
func Logout(completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    backendless?.userService.logout(
        { user in
            print("User logged out.")
            completionHandler(true)
        },
        error: { fault in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
            completionHandler(false)
    })
}
```

And use it

```
Logout() { success in
   print(success)
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why the variables changed in Swift 3? (Also, thank you very much! I'm going to try it when I get back to my computer.)

Comment: You have to take care of the order.

Comment: @vadian   Why is it necessary to place @escaping before the parameter list in this closure? The closure does not seem to escape, it is called within the `func Logout` therefore the @escaping flag should not be specified in Swift 3.

Comment: @bibscy All closures used as an asynchronous callback are `escaping`.

Comment: How do I access the Bool value once getting rid of parameter name success: ?

Comment: @Tamil The value is returned in the closure of the calling method. I updated the answer.

Comment: @vadian i have a method signature getStatus(handler: &(Bool) -> Void)) i am able to access the bool but i am getting the error cannot pass immutable value of type '(Bool) ->()' as inout argument. Why is this error coming?. What does & in the signature mean?

Comment: @Tamil Please ask a new question and add more information.

Answer (score 0):

No need to include Parameter names in Swift 3. auto completion suggest to add @esacping

```
func Logout(completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    backendless?.userService.logout(
        {( user: Any?) -> (Void) in
            print("User logged out.")
            completionHandler(true)
        },
        error: { ( fault : Fault?) -> (Void) in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
            completionHandler(false)
    })
}
```

Comment: Please explain you answer code only answers doesn't tend to help much.