# Closure to return value to outerblock?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like my static function to return a `bool` as such `static func search(email: String?) -> Bool`

I tried to do the commented out part but it getting returned as the return value of the closure. How do I get it to return values to the outer calling function `search(email: String?)`

```
 static func search(email: String?){
        HTTPClient().apiQuery(.GET, endpoint: "user.jsn", params: ["user":["email": email!]], handler: {
            response in
            print(response)
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let successJSON):
                let successResponse = successJSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                if let error = successResponse["errors"] {
                    print(error)
                    // return false
                }
                // else { return true }

            case .Failure :
                print("Failure")
                // return false
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your method signature to return a completion handler with the type you expecting and inside apiQoery just call it when you have the data:

```
static func search(email: String?, completion: (Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> ()){
    ....
    let successResponse = successJSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    completion(successResponse)
    ....
}
```

You can call it like that:

```
YOURCLASSNAME.search(email: nil) {
    responce in
        // Use your dictionary here
}
```

In your case when method returns dictionary but it may returns error would be better to create object which can return both, for example enum Result it's quite popular. See this [link](https://github.com/antitypical/Result) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about static functions but you can use completionHandler like was Objective-C

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39643395/4320266

```
typealias successSearch = () -> Bool

func search(email: String?, isSuccess:successSearch){

}
```

something like this

Hope it helps.